# Second order ODE: $x^4y'' + c^2y = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^4y'' + c^2y = 0 $$

How would you go on about solving this problem? WolframAlpha solved it by substituting $$y=x \cdot v(x)$$ and then letting $$t=\frac{1}{x}$$

Does anyone have a more intuitive way of solving it? If not, why is the substitution exactly $$y=x \cdot v(x)$$?

However, I have never heard of this method before. What I tried to do is naively let $$x^2=u$$, and then proceed to do the equation as an Euler-Cauchy equation. I came to a solution but it is nothing alike the one WolframAlpha provided which leads me to think it can't be solved that way.

Comment: $y=xv(x)$ is a cheap way to knock the $x^4y''$ down to a more reasonable $x^2v''+\text{lower derivatives}$.  If you substitute $x^2=u$ you get an equation of the form $(\alpha uD_u^2+\beta D_u+\gamma)y=0$ which isn't Euler-Cauchy but regular singular point $u=0$ for Frobenius method.

Comment: Mostly, the equations are not solvable by hand. If it is solvable one way is enough and we should feel thankful.

Comment: Unfortunately, almost *no* differential equations have "intuitive" solutions. Usually finding *any* way to solve them, intuitively or not, is enough of a gift.

Comment: The solution is in the book:"DIFFERENTIALGLEICHUNGEN LOSUNGSMETHODEN UND LOSUNGEN" E. KAMKE.